# Centering a table in Firefox

Tags: html, css, html-table, alignment

I've got a small table on one of my pages and I'd like it centered so have coded `<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">`which works fine in IE but the table still left aligns in Firefox.

If i use 
`text-align:center n align:-moz-center`its not working in IE

What do I need to change to get the table to center in Firefox? If I should use `-moz-center` how to make it work in IE?

I'm stuck here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Lekensteyn mentioned, here is some code to show it in action:

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto; text-align:center;">
<table border="1" style="width:200px;">
<tr>
  <td>Hello</td>
  <td>How</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>are</td>
  <td>you?</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

it should center itself based on the `width` & `margin` style definition.

Comment: This won't work unless the div has a set width. By default, block level elements have a width of 100%.

Answer (score 6):

Add `margin: auto;` to the table. That is the standard way to do it.